# Как вывести system.pagenavigation над каталогом?

Tags: php, веб-программирование, битрикс

У меня есть свой шаблон system.pagination
Я его вывожу под списком каталога. Но мне еще нужно вывести его над каталогом, но не стандартной фией "показать над", а мне нужно его впихнуть в комплексный компонент каталога, где он будет находиться выше на 4-5 дивов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С помощью отложенных функций. Они позволяют выводить HTML до вызова того компонента, которые его генерирует.

http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/?COURSE_ID=43&LESSON_ID=3489

Comment: вопрос.
Я пробовал выводить через [эту функцию](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/reference/cmain/showviewcontent.php), но для этого в шаблоне пагинации мне пришлось дублировать еще раз весь код убрав его в функцию для буфера. Но потом при вызове перед каталогам, мне пагинация вывелась 2 раза...

Answer (score 0):

В общем, я перенес все блоки в template.php в секцшион. и там простым подключением пагинации реализовал ее сверху нужных блоков.
Но буду благодарен, если кто-то подскажет, как можно было ее решить пред. методом?